# Create functions/file dependency graph of a node console app

Tags: visual-studio-code, graph, dependencies

I have a node.js console app project written using functional programming.
I want create a diagram which shows me all the function and the filenames where they are contained that are called from a given entry point.

Kind of [Dependency Graph](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sz-p.dependencygraph) but this one gets lost when dependencies are imported from a `index.ts` and then you don't know if the objects are actually used or if the appear just because they are part of the module. And it doesn't show the name of the single functions, just the file names.

Is there a tool that can do this job?

I use VSCode but I can download also other IDE if needed.